# Creating Extra Button with only Paragraph Functionality in Jodit WYSIWYG HTML Editor

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I'm working on a small CMS application, and I've been using Jodit editor (v3) as the WYSIWYG html editor. This is mainly because I'm rendering in the current text with EJS, and other editors didn't want to render that info properly into other WYSIWYG editors (CKEditor, TinyMCE, Quill). For this project, Jodit has been installed and configured through npm and grunt.

I'm having trouble creating an extra button with the functionality of formatting the current selection to a paragraph. The editor comes with 'paragraph' functionality, but this drop down includes headings and a quote formatting option, which I don't want the user to have (for the moment). The extra button in this example doesn't have an icon yet, but you are still able to click the button next to the current "paragraph" option.

Jodit editor (v3): https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/

Jodit editor methods: https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/methods/

**Relevant HTML:** (note: I am rendering the text inside the editor using EJS normally, but I believe this sample info will suffice)

```
<textarea name="value" class="form-control" id="html-editor"><h1>Testing</h1><p>Lorem ipsum ....</p></textarea>
```

**Relevant JS:**

```
var editor = new Jodit('#html-editor', {
      buttons: ['bold','italic', 'paragraph'],
      extraButtons: [{
        name: 'OnlyParagraph',
        icon: '',
        exec: (editor) => {
          var selection = editor.selection;
          var text = editor.selection.getHTML();
          console.log(text);
          var html = '<p>' + text + '</p>'
          console.log(html);
          editor.selection.remove();
          editor.selection.insertHTML(html);
        }
      }]
    });
```

Essentially, I want to be able to select my

element and turn it into a paragraph. Is this isn't easily accomplishable with an extra buttons, can the default dropdown of the 'paragraph' button be adapted to only offer the paragraph formatting option (none of the heading or quote options are desired at this point in time).

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cop-out, but using this CSS:

```
.jodit_toolbar_btn-h1,
.jodit_toolbar_btn-h2,
.jodit_toolbar_btn-h3,
.jodit_toolbar_btn-h4,
.jodit_toolbar_btn-blockquote {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Will hide all but the "Normal" button for the paragraph dropdown.